# How to convert List<Object[]> array to an array of strings that prints results one by one?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, object

I have a java program that runs a query, generates a list, then prints the list of objects like so:

code

```
System.out.println("running");
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(env.getProperty("buyback-feedback"));  
        for (Object[] array : resultList2) {
            for (Object field : array) {
                System.out.println("->" + field);
```

output

```
.....
->2022-07-15 10:00:25.0
->2859826
->P
->3325
->123
```

Now I'd like to convert that list of objects to be an array of strings that can be printed out one by one. That way I can take (for example) the third string in the array and use that value to run other functions in my code. But I can't do that with objects which is why I need to convert all objects to strings.

Now I tried to convert a list of objects to an array of strings like so:

```
        List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) q.getResultList();
        String[] array = new String[resultList.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for (Object value : resultList) {
            array[index] = String.valueOf( value );
//          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
            System.out.println("->"+value);
            index++;
        }
```

But the output is "->[Ljava.lang.Object;@c7b901" instead of the array of strings I was hoping for.

What modifications does my code need to convert the list of objects to an array of strings?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. A `List<Object[]>` is essentially a 2D array. What do you want to do with that? How does that map to a `String[]`? Or do you want a `List<String[]>`?

Comment: I'd like a list <string[] >

Comment: Why do you think that's going to behave any differently form the `List<Object[]>`, if you're only planning to print the individual elements?

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you want to convert List<Object[]> to String[] (ie an array of strings) . If that's the case there is a function that you can use to shorten your code.

It's called the *toArray* function. And you can find an example of the function in use on this page: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-program-to-convert-a-list-to-an-array

Within the listToArray class, you'll see that a list is created first that will then call the *toArray* function. But prior to the calling of the function, the example code shows the creation of your String[] called myArray.

Lastly, the example uses a loop to show or prove that the contents were properly transferred.

I would advise you to first copy, paste and run this code to double check that it works as it should. Then, you can slowly merge the code with your code and re-run it to see that everything is still functioning properly.